# How to get list of item from restsharp api response

Tags: c#

I am calling a api and getting list of ids in json format in restsharp api response. But problem i am unable to write the syntax for List in restsharp  Execute method. Please check the code bellow. And correct my List<> Syntax.

```
var client2 = new RestClient(apiEndPoint);
var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
var Result2 = client.Execute<List><PageIds>(request);
```

My id model:

```
class PageIds
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay i think this is your answer-

```
var Result2 = client.Execute<List<PageIds>>(request);
```

However until we see your json response cant sure this will work or not. But at-least it is the correct syntax for `List` on this particular situation.